# PHP Functions - Notice: Undefined variables problem

Tags: php, function

I created two functions both functions used to work before I turned them into functions and now I get the following errors `Notice: Undefined variable: link, url and depth` and I was wondering how can I fix this problem so they can work. The problem comes from the last piece of code `allCategories($link[0], $url, 0, $depth+1);` which I believe stems from the second function.

Function 1

```
function allCategories($parent = 0, $parent_url = '', $count = 0, $depth = 0){
    catQuery();
    global $link;           
    if($count == 0){
        echo '<ol>';
    } else {
    echo '<ol>';
    }

    foreach ($parent as $id => $cat) {
    if($cat['parent_id'] == '0'){
            $url = $parent_url . $cat['url'];
            $url = str_replace('&#063;cat=', '', $url);
            echo '<li><a href="http://www.example.com/cat/' . strip_tags($url) . '" title="' . strip_tags($cat['category']) . ' Category Link" class="category-headers">' . strip_tags($cat['category']) . '</a>';          
    } else {
            $indent = str_repeat('&nbsp; ', $depth * 1);
            $url = $parent_url . $cat['url'];
            $cat_num = array('&#063;cat=','&#038;sub1=','&#038;sub2='');
            $url = str_replace($cat_num, '/', $url);
            echo '<li>' . $indent . '<a href="http://www.example.com/cat/' . strip_tags($url) . '" title="' . strip_tags($cat['category']) . ' Category Link">' . strip_tags($cat['category']) . '</a>';
    }

        if(isset($link[$id])) {
            allCategories($link[$id], $url, $count+1, $depth+1);
    }               
            echo '</li>';
    }       
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

Function 2

```
function catQuery(){
    $cat_dbc = mysqli_query(database(),"SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id, category LIKE '%more%', category ASC");
    if (!$cat_dbc) {
            trigger_error(mysqli_error(database()));
    }

    $link = array();
    while(list($id, $parent_id, $category, $url, $depth) = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_dbc)){
            $link[$parent_id][$id] = array('parent_id' => $parent_id, 'category' => $category, 'url' => $url, 'depth' => $depth);
    }
}
```

Display the desired output.

```
allCategories($link[0], $url, 0, $depth+1);
```

Comment: You've shown your usage: `allCategories($link[0], $url, 0, $depth+1);` but none of the code from above this line; do you set the $link, $url and $depth variables?

Comment: it should come from Function 2

Comment: @SLEEP: That is not how [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) works.

Comment: It doesn't really help you that you create new accounts and severe your question history by that. This posting is just a variation of your previous code, but it's unclear how you broke it. Also you might benefit from an IDE with minimal variable tracing.

Comment: well first of I only had two other accounts but could not log in to each of them so this one is my new one.

Answer (score 2):

The answer Write code that does not try to access undefined variables. If you are a beginner, you might want to read a recent book about PHP5.

In your second function, you forgot `global $link;`. However, better `return $link;` and use `$link = catQuery();` in your first function instead of this horrible abuse of global variables

For the other undefined vars.. did you define `$link`, `$url` and `$depth` before calling `allCategories($link[0], $url, 0, $depth+1);`?

Comment: This answer does not help me at all.

Comment: This does not solve my problem at all.

Comment: Then wat about being more specific? For example, show us the **lines** where your code emits those notices.

Comment: I thought I did mention it its the line where the code is `allCategories($link[0], $url, 0, $depth+1);`

Comment: Ah.. well then the answer is already in my answer - see the last line!

Comment: Where will I define link and url?

Comment: Despite having been pretty unhelpful initially, ThiefMaster is right - you will be better served showing us more of the code surrounding the `allCategories($link[0], $url, 0, $depth+1);` - it looks like you are getting confused about how variables/functions/scope works, but without further information it's hard to help.

Comment: That depends on your code. Since we don't know anything but the code you showed us you should know that - it could be coming from a session, GET/POST data, etc...

Comment: I don't know what to show you as this is all my code?

Comment: @SLEEP: A [complete, minimal testcase](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml) that demonstrates the problem with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal this dosen't help my current problem though.

Comment: @SLEEP: It will help you to ask a better question, which will help you to get more quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

change the end of function catQuery like this

```
    while(list($id, $parent_id, $category, $url, $depth) = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_dbc)){
            $link[$parent_id][$id] = array('parent_id' => $parent_id, 'category' => $category, 'url' => $url, 'depth' => $depth);
    }
   return $link;
}
```

then change the start of the allCategories function like this

```
function allCategories($parent = 0, $parent_url = '', $count = 0, $depth = 0){
    $link = catQuery();
    // global $link;           
    if($count == 0){
```

the reason why it didn't work is that you would need to have "global $link;" defined in each function. but global variables are not good practice, so best to return $link from catQuery function and then use it locally inside the allCategories function

Comment: I still get the same problem:(

Comment: Apparently he's also trying to use the variables from inside the function when calling it